# Attempting to figure out the correct type for this

Tags: scala, slick, typing

Apologies, this is going to be a somewhat noob-ish question. I have an object from the slick library that has at type like this:

```
Query[(Rep[String], Rep[String]), (String, String), Seq]
```

I'm trying to write a function which accepts queries as arguments, though the sequences in them are of uncertain length - ie, it could equally well be:

```
Query[(Rep[String], Rep[String], Rep[String]), (String, String, String), Seq]
```

So the first two components have three elements rather than two. I cannot figure out how this is done. I have tried various erroneous permutations, like `Query[Product[Rep[String]], Product[String], Seq]`, to no avail, and even what I assumed would be the nuclear option of just using `Any` doesn't work. My error messages are along the lines of

```
[error]  found   : Option[slick.driver.H2Driver.api.Query[(slick.driver.H2Driver.api.Rep[String], slick.driver.H2Driver.api.Rep[String]),(String, St
ring),Seq]]
[error]     (which expands to)  Option[slick.lifted.Query[(slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[String]),(String, String),Seq]]
[error]  required: Option[slick.driver.H2Driver.api.Rep[scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]]]]
[error]     (which expands to)  Option[slick.lifted.Rep[scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]]]]
[error]       ReturnFunctions.completeQuery(db, query, serialize_and_send)
```

I think my inability to solve this may reflect some fundamental lack of understanding about scala, strongly typed languages in general and possibly also computing as a whole. Should I be resolving this Query to some more definite form before I try to even pass it into a function? I also suspect I'm not interpreting the original type correctly - what do the parantheses mean in this context? Is it that Query is expecting to receive three sets of parameters, one after the other, like when you do fn(arg1)(arg2)(arg3) = ...?

Any help with this troubling dilemma gratefully received.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also suspect I'm not interpreting the original type correctly - what do the parentheses mean in this context?

You're looked at a reasonable advanced area, but let's try to help.

The `Query` type always has three type parameters. You'll see them written as `Query[M, U, C]`.

The first parameter, `M`, is a tuple. That's what the parentheses mean in this context.

In your first example, `M` is a tuple of two elements; and in the second it's three. The same situation exists for the second parameter, `U`. There's a bit more detail on this in [Essential Slick](https://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html#queryTypes).

In Scala, you can have generic parameters. That means you can say something along the lines of:

```
def foo[M, U, C[_]](q: Query[M,U,C]) = ???
```

We've defined a method with:

- three type parameters; and
- taking an argument of a query that has those types.

We've not said anything about `M`, `U`, or much about `C` (other than that it's a type that takes a type as an argument). That means there's not a lot we can do with them, but you may not need to.

A post on [query enrichment in Slick](https://richard.dallaway.com/2015/05/15/slick-enrichment.html) gives a longer (related) example which may be of use.

As Dmytro suggests, a better route would be to create a concrete example of what you'd like to achieve and work from there.

Comment: thank you for this. I also noticed that you answered one of my earliest questions about the slick MySQL driver so I presume you're quite closely connected to the slick package itself - if so then thanks for your work because it's a real pleasure to use.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the shape of [`Query`](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/eecc74fa1ba8e477e6fbd991b5b9bbb87b8f3918/slick/src/main/scala/slick/lifted/Query.scala#L23) type constructor

```
Query[+E, U, C[_]]
```

We say `Query` is a type *constructor* because it constructs a concrete type out of given type arguments `E`, `U`, and `C[_]`, similarly to how a function constructs a concrete value out of given function arguments.

Now lets try to deconstruct the concrete type

```
Query[(Rep[String], Rep[String]), (String, String), Seq]
```

into its constituent type parameters. We have

```
E     = (Rep[String], Rep[String])
U     = (String, String)
C[_]  = Seq
```

Note `(A, B)` is just syntactic sugar for `Tuple2[A, B]` thus

```
E     = (Rep[String], Rep[String]) = Tuple2[Rep[String], Rep[String]]
U     = (String, String)           = Tuple2[String, String]
C[_]  = Seq                        = Seq
```

You might be wondering about that underscore in `C[_]`. This specifies that the type parameter `C` must be a type constructor as opposed to a concrete type. For example `Seq` is a type constructor whilst `Seq[Int]` is not. Furthermore, you might be wondering about that `+` in `+E`. This specifies the inheritance relationship of parameterised types, or in other words, variance, for example, it specifies whether `Seq[Dog]` a subtype of `Seq[Animal]`.

Lastly lets write the resulting concrete type in its full verbosity

```
Query[Tuple2[Rep[String], Rep[String]], Tuple2[String, String], Seq]
```

Comment: thanks - that's a clear explanation. I need to do some further reading on these concepts but you've given me some leads to follow.